# How to call the BatchNormalization layer with available statistics (mean , var , beta, gamma)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am implementing a neural network in tf-keras, where I have to use `BatchNormalization` layer, preferably using keras but instead of training I am using it for inference but highly confused about how to provide the available statistics to `tf.keras.BatchNormalization` call.
As I understood from various sources and official documentation, there is no way of providing the data explicitly to `tf.keras.BatchNormalization` call and if you desire to use it in inference mode then you have to train using the same call and making `training = true`.

Comment: Since you would supply all the parameters, you don't need a `BatchNormalization` layer. Instead, implement a custom `Layer` which can perform the operation as `BatchNormalization` does. See the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization) for more details.

Comment: The statistics are stored as weights of that layer, so you just need to call set_weights with an appropriate built list of np arrays.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy , that worked , thanks

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal , i also used tf.nn.batchnormalization , and it worked fine. similar to using a custom bn implementation but not creating one. thanks